# Why is the font element not supported in HTML5?

Tags: html

I am just curious really and hope that someone can reveal the method in the madness of the W3C.
What is the reason for not supporting this element in the latest HTML5 standard?
I know the element was deprecated in HTML 4.01, but I don't understand why.

It seemed perfectly logical to me, you have a a paragraph of text and just wish to change the font, or to identify, lines or words from it using the font element, now the only way to do the job is with the span element.
It seems strange to me that there are so many ways to create a block of text, using div, section, or just paragraph, but to wrap a few keywords or any inline content, there is only the span element.

And really, one little element can't do any harm, so why not still support it?

Thank you,

Luke

Comment: Well, you can add 'style="font-family: xxx"' to just about any tag to achieve the same thing and it's a lot more flexible. Even better, assign a class to the text and set it's font in the CSS document. Then when you have a huge document and you want to change all the headings from Times New Roman to Comic Sans you can do so in one place rather than having to find all the font tags AND for each one decide if you want to change it or if it had the same font by coincidence.

Comment: Because HTML aims to be semantic, i.e. describe *what* should be presented. The font tag has absolutely no semantic meaning, it is purely mechanical: it describes *how* something should be presented. The way to control the mechanics of presentation is CSS, not HTML. The "one little tag" argument does not hold water because you can use it for hundreds of little tags if considered individually.

Comment: Actually a `style="font-family: xxx;` is rather no-go in HTML too. Style should be kept out of HTML as much as possible.

Comment: The question asks for speculations and opinions and does not deal with practical programming/authoring problems. Moreover, it is based on false premises. HTML5 declares `font` as obsolete and non-conforming, but it also defines its meaning and requires browsers to continue supporting it, see http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#phrasing-content-0 (Moreover, there are many tags that can be used “to wrao a few keywords or any inline content”, such as `i`, `b`, `em`, and `cite`.)

Comment: I could also say that i, b, em also serve the same purpose as the font tag, to change the style of text.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In short:

HTML is a markup language. Use it to mark up the different sections of your content using the most semantically accurate element.

CSS is used for styling purposes, such as changing colors, sizes, fonts, etc.

The `<font>` element was used for styling, not marking up a section of your content. That's why it's deprecated, along with other out-of-place elements such as `<center>`.

Comment: Thanks, that's kinda what I thought. But I still say that <font> is a useful tag, and I am sad to see it go.

Comment: Except that in HTML5, `<u>` has semantics and is not obsolete.

Comment: @Alohci, `<u>` is in fact deprecated. There's no semantic value attached to it. As you can see in the [HTML5 reference](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/), it's no longer listed as an element. It's instead recommended to use another text-level element and apply underline with CSS.

Comment: @NilsKaspersson - Here's the link to the `<u>` element in HTML5. http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/CR/text-level-semantics.html#the-u-element. It was deprecated in HTML 4.01, but is not any more. In fact *nothing* is "deprecated" in HTML5. Some elements are ["obsolete"](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/CR/obsolete.html#obsolete) but the `<u>` element is not among them.

Comment: Also, the HTML5 reference document you link to is three years out of date and is not being maintained.

Comment: It seems like you're right. I wonder where I learned <u> was deprecated. I'll edit it out of the answer above. :-)

Comment: Interesting fact (maybe), Chrome uses the `<center>` tag on the new design of it's "New Tab" page, and on the Google search page

Comment: Ok, does this mean that `<b>` and `<i>` tags are deprecated too?  I'm finding that there's this trend now to use specific font names and no longer respect bold and italic tags.  For example, in Flash CC font names must use the unique font titles such as "Times New Roman Bold" and it ignores the bold and italic text format options.  This seems to be a trend on the web now (google web fonts, etc), as discussed here: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/02/14/setting-weights-and-styles-at-font-face-declaration/

Comment: No, the `<b>` and `<i>` elements carry semantic meaning so they're not deprecated. 

I fail to see what thay has to do with different formatting of fonts, though, since you'd simply change the font-face to the bold font-face instead of the font-weight.

Comment: The simplest explanation of the effect is that there is no longer a clear concept of a bold or italicized font.  They are now distinct fonts with distinct names.  So what becomes of pages that use `<i>` and `<b>` tags to mean bold and italic?  ...continued...

Comment: If only the original regular font family was specified, the browser will have to decide between two options: 1. do nothing to the text wrapped in the `<i>` tag by default or 2. alter the existing font to appear italic by rendering it slanted.  If it does nothing, existing pages break.  If it takes option #2 and slants the text and the CSS also specifies a specifically italic font, then you'll end up with a double-slanted font.  It also breaks programming APIs that have a "TextFormat" object with bold and italic properties.

Comment: @Triynko, you're kind of overthinking it. If you setup your font-face rules to only use one name for the font-family, but change the src, font-weight and font-style to whatever is right, then browsers know very well what to do. Take a look at how [Google Fonts](http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,400italic) setup their font-families. [...]

Comment: That said, there's still use for the `<i>`, `<em>`, `<b>` and `<strong>` elements. The `<strong>` element [represents strong importance](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/CR/text-level-semantics.html#the-strong-element), while the `<b>` element is primarily used for [utilitarian purposes with no implied additional importance](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/CR/text-level-semantics.html#the-b-element). [...]

Comment: In a similar fashion, the `<em>` element represents [stress emphasis](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/CR/text-level-semantics.html#the-em-element), whereas the `<i>` element represents [text read in an alternate voice or mood](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/CR/text-level-semantics.html#the-i-element).

Answer (score 4):

HTML tags describe their contents. To mark up your HTML you should use CSS. In such way you can create different skins for the same information. Since the `font` tag serves purely visual purpose, it has no place in HTML; it does not describe the contents.

With describing contents I mean: "This is paragraph of text / this is a time / this is a link to another page / this is the title of this article / this is a list of related terms / this is a table containing test results" etc.

Read up on semantic HTML, it will hopefully make things more clear for you.

Comment: Wouldn't that also be true of <i>, <b>, <em> ... ? These tags are for purely visual purposes.

Comment: @LukeTO'Brien - Not in HTML5. Each of those elements has a defined, non-presentational meaning, and therefore should not be used when not conveying that specific meaning, even if is happens to display the content in the fashion that you want.

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of ways to wrap inline content, but only one of them has no semantics associated with it (span). Of the list of block wrappers you gave, only div has no semantics associated with it.

The old font element has no semantics associated with it, so it contributes as much as span and can be replaced by span.

The idea is that you pick the element that describes *why* the text looks different ([`<em>`, `<cite>`, `<dfn>`, etc](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#phrasing-content)) and then apply CSS to make it look the way you want.

> And really, one little tag can't do any harm, so why not still support it?

It *is* supported, the [rendering rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html) describe how browsers should handle the font element. This is for backwards compatibility. Authors are just forbidden from using it (since it does no good).