# I want to display the quantity of the selected item of a drop down list in a textbox. The data is stored in database

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

The code for retrieving data from database into Drop Down List.

```
<%
    DataSource data = new MysqlDataSource();
    Connection con =  data.getConnection("root","system");
    System.out.println("Connected to MySQL");
    PreparedStatement pre = con.prepareStatement("select * from library.booklist");
    ResultSet result = pre.executeQuery();
%>
<tr>
<font color="black" size="5"> <td> Book List : </td> </font>
<td> <select name= "BookList" id="booklist" onchange="show()">
<option> - select - </option>
<%
while (result.next())
{
   String name = result.getString("Book");
   System.out.println("Output Done");
%>
<option value="<%=name%>"> <%=name%></option>
<%
}
%>
</select></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<%

/* my code for displaying quantity is below but it's not working. I am new to jsp, so don't know how to populate the textbox. */

String value = request.getParameter("BookList");
pre = con.prepareStatement("select Quantity from library.booklist where Book = ? ");
result = pre.executeQuery();
%>
<font color="black" size="5"><td> Quantity : </td>
<%
while (result.next())
{
    int quantity = result.getInt("Quantity");
    System.out.println("quantity dikha raha hai");
%>
<input name = "Quantity" type = "text" size = "25" readonly = "readonly" value = "<%=quantity%>"> <%=quantity%> </input>
<%
}
%>
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: when u say its not working... what's happening, are you getting an error, or the textfield does not have a value?

Comment: the error is the price and quantity of last item in the database is getting populated into the textbox. This should'nt be the case. I want to display the quantity and price of an item selected from a drop down list into a textbox. How can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

### Edit

You need to pass your `BookList` parameter to your prepared statement:

```
String value = request.getParameter("BookList");
pre = con.prepareStatement("select Quantity from library.booklist where Book = ? ");

pre.setString(1, value); // <------

result = pre.executeQuery();
```

Otherwise your query does not know which Book to select.

### Original

You haven't said what the actual problem is, but your HTML markup has problems that definitely aren't helping.

1. Don't use the `<font>` tag.  It is [not supported in
   HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19000883/701303).
2. Your second `<font>` needs a closing `</font>`.
3. You have a closing `</td>` tag at the end with no opening `<td>`.
4. The [`<input>` tag is a **void element**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input), meaning it does not accept content between opening and closing tags.  Write it as `<input type="text" name="Quantity" ...`**`/>`**

Clean up those things and your problem might be fixed, or at least more obvious.

Comment: I have rectified all my mistakes but my problem is the price and quantity of last item in the database is getting populated into the textbox. This shouldn't be the case. I want to display the quantity and price of an item selected from a drop down list into a textbox. How can i do it?

Comment: I am passing a list of items.. So i need to pass array..          String [] value =  request.getParameterValues("BookList");               but how will the quantity and price change on changing the item?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to pass an array to the query you posted. Please update the question with your actual code.  Also please include the code for your `show()` function.