# Create a table to encompass part of data

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, datatable

I am trying to take part group of variables and add the information to a table. I have been able to add a table to encompass all the information displayed, however it does not place the information into a table that I want to see. Here is what the inital looks like (to new here to imput images): https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ektdb.png - the red boxes is the information that I want divided into a table.

The information is pulled from a Sharepoint database using a soap function. I am including the place where all the variables are called:

```
function processResultOON(xData, status) 
{
    var result, subresult, outString="";
    var ListTemp = new Array();
    var ListUpdated = new Array();
    var floatlat;
    var floatlng;
    var floatlatdist;
    var floatlngdist;
    var floatdist;
    var floatdiststr;
    var titletxt;
    var biznametxt;
    var addresstxt;
    var citytxt;
    var phonetxt;
    var faxtxt;
    var websitetxt;
    var notestxt;
    var cleanstr;
    var ndx;
    var placendx;
    var swapped;
    var loopcnt;
    var maxndx;
    var tempbizname;
    var tempaddr;
    var tempcity;
    var temptitle;
    var tempphone;
    var tempfax;
    var tempnotes;
    var tempwebsite;
    var tempdist;
    var templat;
    var templon;
    var floattarglat;
    var floattarglon;
    var floatsamplat;
    var floatsamplon;
    var posel;
    var vccsel;
    var towltsel;
    var towmedsel;
    var towhvysel;
    var lowboysel;
    var dolliessel;
    var motorcyclesel;
    var tireltsel;
    var tiremedsel;
    var tirehvysel;
    var winchsel;
    var fuelsel;
    var lockssel;
    var locksmithsel;
    var jumpsel;
    var selOVN;
    var notesstage;
    var clearanceheight;
    var currentinsertptr;
    var currentlowdistptr;
    var lowdistcheck;
    var currentlowdist;
    var checkptr;
    var dropoutndx;

    var title_ndx = 0;
    var city_ndx = 1;
    var businessname_ndx = 2;
    var address_ndx = 3;
    var phone_ndx = 4;
    var fax_ndx = 5;
    var notes_ndx = 6;
    var lat_ndx = 7;
    var lon_ndx = 8;
    var website_ndx = 9;
    var po_ndx = 10;
    var vcc_ndx = 11;
    var lowboy_ndx = 12;
    var dollies_ndx = 13;
    var motorcycle_ndx = 14;
    var winch_ndx = 15;
    var fuel_ndx = 16;
    var locks_ndx = 17;
    var locksmith_ndx = 18;
    var jump_ndx = 19;
    var OVN_ndx = 20;
    var towlt_ndx = 21;
    var towmed_ndx = 22;
    var towhvy_ndx = 23;
    var tirelt_ndx = 24;
    var tiremed_ndx = 25;
    var tirehvy_ndx = 26;
    var clearance_ndx = 27;
    var dist_ndx = 28;

    var arrayndx;

    var addtolist;
    var addpin;


    var d2 = new Date();
    n2 = d2.getTime();



    var count = 0;

    try 
    {
        if (status == "success" && result)
        {
            $(result).find("rs\\:data").each(function() 
            {
                subresult = $(this);

                $(subresult).find("z\\:row").each(function()
                {
                    count++;
                    });

                ListI = new Array(count);
                for(var i=0;i<ListI.length;i++)
                {
                    ListI[i] = new Array(29); 
                    }

                var d2a1 = new Date();
                n2a1 = d2a1.getTime();

                arrayndx = 0;

                $(subresult).find("z\\:row").each(function()
                {
                    ListI[arrayndx][title_ndx] = $(this).attr("ows_Title")
                    ListI[arrayndx][city_ndx] = $(this).attr("ows_City")
                    ListI[arrayndx][businessname_ndx] = $(this).attr("ows_Business_x0020_Name")
                    ListI[arrayndx][address_ndx] = $(this).attr("ows_Address")
                    ListI[arrayndx][phone_ndx] = $(this).attr("ows_Phone")
                    ListI[arrayndx][fax_ndx] = $(this).attr("ows_Fax")
                    ListI[arrayndx][notes_ndx] = $(this).attr("ows_Notes")
                    ListI[arrayndx][lat_ndx] = $(this).attr("ows_Lat")
                    ListI[arrayndx][lon_ndx] = $(this).attr("ows_Lon")
                    ListI[arrayndx][website_ndx] = $(this).attr("ows_Website")
                    ListI[arrayndx][po_ndx] = $(this).attr("ows_PO")
                    ListI[arrayndx][vcc_ndx] = $(this).attr("ows_VCC")
                    ListI[arrayndx][lowboy_ndx] = $(this).attr("ows_Lowboy")
                    ListI[arrayndx][dollies_ndx] = $(this).attr("ows_Dollies")
                    ListI[arrayndx][motorcycle_ndx] = $(this).attr("ows_Motorcycle")
                    ListI[arrayndx][winch_ndx] = $(this).attr("ows_Winch")
                    ListI[arrayndx][fuel_ndx] = $(this).attr("ows_Fuel")
                    ListI[arrayndx][locks_ndx] = $(this).attr("ows_Locks")
                    ListI[arrayndx][locksmith_ndx] = $(this).attr("ows_Locksmith")
                    ListI[arrayndx][jump_ndx] = $(this).attr("ows_Jump")
                    ListI[arrayndx][OVN_ndx] = $(this).attr("ows_OVN")
                    ListI[arrayndx][towlt_ndx] = $(this).attr("ows_Tow_x0020_light")
                    ListI[arrayndx][towmed_ndx] = $(this).attr("ows_Tow_x0020_medium")
                    ListI[arrayndx][towhvy_ndx] = $(this).attr("ows_Tow_x0020_heavy")
                    ListI[arrayndx][tirelt_ndx] = $(this).attr("ows_Tires_x0020_light")
                    ListI[arrayndx][tiremed_ndx] = $(this).attr("ows_Tires_x0020_medium")
                    ListI[arrayndx][tirehvy_ndx] = $(this).attr("ows_Tires_x0020_heavy")
                    ListI[arrayndx][clearance_ndx] = $(this).attr("ows_Clearance")
                    ListI[arrayndx][dist_ndx] = 0.0;

                    arrayndx++;
                    }
                    );
                });


            arrayndx = 0;

            outheader="<tr>"
            for (j in ListI[0])
            {
                outheader = outheader + "<th>" + j +"</th>";
                }
            outheader = outheader + "</tr>"
            outString = outString + "<table>";
```

The information is then displayed to the show as it does in the image above using the below code. It is this information that I want to have put into a table. The question would be how do I put this information in a table without including the above unrelated information into the table?

```
posel = ListTemp[i][po_ndx];
vccsel = ListTemp[i][vcc_ndx];
towltsel = ListTemp[i][towlt_ndx];
towmedsel = ListTemp[i][towmed_ndx];
towhvysel = ListTemp[i][towhvy_ndx];
lowboysel = ListTemp[i][lowboy_ndx];
dolliessel = ListTemp[i][dollies_ndx];
motorcyclesel = ListTemp[i][motorcycle_ndx];
tireltsel = ListTemp[i][tirelt_ndx];
tiremedsel = ListTemp[i][tiremed_ndx];
tirehvysel = ListTemp[i][tirehvy_ndx];
winchsel = ListTemp[i][winch_ndx];
fuelsel = ListTemp[i][fuel_ndx];
lockssel = ListTemp[i][locks_ndx];
locksmithsel = ListTemp[i][locksmith_ndx];
jumpsel = ListTemp[i][jump_ndx];
selOVN = ListTemp[i][OVN_ndx];
clearanceheight = ListTemp[i][clearance_ndx];


notesstage = "";

if (posel == 1)
{
    notesstage = notesstage + "<strong>PO </strong>";
}
if (vccsel == 1)
{
    notesstage = notesstage + "VCC ";
}
if ((towltsel == 1) || (towmedsel == 1) || (towhvysel == 1))
{
    notesstage = notesstage + "<b>Tow</b>: ";
    if (towltsel == 1)
    {
        notesstage = notesstage + "<font color=#892EE4><b>LD </b></font>";
    }
    if (towmedsel == 1)
    {
        notesstage = notesstage + "<font color=#008080><b>MD </b></font>";
    }
    if (towhvysel == 1)
    {
        notesstage = notesstage + "<font color=#1FCB4A><b>HD </b></font>";
    }
}
if (lowboysel == 1)
{
    notesstage = notesstage + "Lowboy ";
}
if (dolliessel == 1)
{
    notesstage = notesstage + "Dollies ";
}
if (motorcyclesel == 1)
{
    notesstage = notesstage + "Motorcycle ";
}
if ((tireltsel == 1) || (tiremedsel == 1) || (tirehvysel == 1))
{
    notesstage = notesstage + "<b>Tires</b> ";
    if (tireltsel == 1)
    {
        notesstage = notesstage + "<font color=#892EE4><b>LD </b></font>";
    }
    if (tiremedsel == 1)
    {
        notesstage = notesstage + "<font color=#008080><b>MD </b></font>";
    }
    if (tirehvysel == 1)
    {
        notesstage = notesstage + "<font color=#1FCB4A><b>HD </b></font>";
    }
}
```

Comment: what is your question? WHy all the deprecated font tags?

Comment: the font tags change the how it displays when it finally loads - I only wanted part of the objects bolded rather then all of it - for the sake of visual ease.

The question is how do I turn the data on the second half into a table without including the other data in the table.

Comment: use css for that, there are old style related tags like font that are now deprecated...see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19000883/why-is-the-font-tag-not-supported-in-html5

Comment: Yeah I know they are slightly outdated, but they work for now and do what they need to. The issue at hand is creating a table out of part of the data

Comment: as far as table goes, pass array of objects to a javascript template engine. Or manually create strings from an `each` loop.